# Sci-fi episode from the late 50's or early 60s about an isolated couple and magic food

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, science-fiction

I believe this was a Sci-Fi TV episode, not a movie but I could be wrong. It was basically about an elderly man and woman living alone in an isolated house or maybe lighthouse in some kind of sea setting or maybe trapped on an island.

Anyway a young man turns up and has to stay with them and soon discovers that the couple has only one kind of food to eat, which is some kind of white spongy substance the older man finds in the sea. The trick is that it will taste exactly like any food you want to eat. After overcoming initial revulsion the younger man imagined a steak and voilà, the spongy stuff tasted exactly like steak.

Answer (score 3):

[Substance X](http://www.tv.com/shows/tales-of-tomorrow/substance-x-131366/), the 1952 episode from the American science fiction anthology show *Tales of Tomorrow*, has a very similar plot, but it's a young woman who visits the town, not a man. From a [related article](http://firstwefeast.com/drink/2015/06/the-absurd-history-of-artificial-flavors):

> In a 1952 episode of the sci-fi series Tales of Tomorrow, a rogue government scientist — who else? — discovers **the perfect food.** Called “Substance X,” it’s nutritious, easily **synthesized from seawater, and tastes like whatever the customer wants**, even changing from bite to bite. The inevitable catch? It’s highly addictive, causing the episode’s fictional Texas town to devolve into chaos.

Unfortunately, I can't find any images or clips, but I'll try to track some down and add them in. For now, perhaps the show's brief intro might jog your memory: